# Why is gem so incredibly slow on my Debian Lenny server?

Tags: debian, ruby, gem

Here's what I've got so far:

```
# gem install passenger
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed rack-1.2.1
Successfully installed passenger-2.2.15
2 gems installed
Installing ri documentation for rack-1.2.1...
Installing ri documentation for passenger-2.2.15...
Installing RDoc documentation for rack-1.2.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for passenger-2.2.15...
```

... but it's been stuck on "Installing RDoc documentation for passenger-2.2.15" for maybe 30 mins now. I'm a bit worried to kill it, since this could lead to a corrupt install.

Also, I've noticed that `gem` in general has been painfully slow compared to say, `apt-get` - is this normal?

Comment: Hmm, weird, the SSH session just terminated. But I'm still connected to other sessions on that machine. Very very strange...

Answer (score 2):

Gem is slow (at least compared to apt I've found). It will run faster if you don't generate the documentation: `--no-ri --no-rdoc`

Comment: Thanks, I think that'll help! Documentation install is always so extremely slow, which sounds silly.

Comment: That's because the documentation is generated from the RDoc comments in the `.rb` files. `apt` is only faster in this regard because it will just extract the documentation from the `.deb` archives.

Answer (score 0):

Re-running the command seems to have worked a 2nd time. But I'm still very worried that it just hung for 30 mins.